# SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().removeTransactionObserver(self) Removing and adding

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, deinit

Right so i have this game on the app store called misshapen, in my game i have in app purchases which work fine however i have found a bug which will make the game crash if someone presses the in app purchase button then goes to the main menu (the IAP is on the options screen) if the user then go back to option and clicks of IAP the game crashes because there is already a transaction observer.

To fix my issue the line of code i need is

```
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().removeTransactionObserver(self)
```

but im not sure where to call it because if it is called wrong then it promts the user will apple login screen all the time. My fix was to call it in

```
 deinit {    
        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().removeTransactionObserver(self)
        }
}
```

this works and fixes my issue but when the user is returned to the menu the user gets promted with apple login screen and i dont want this!! Please help me thank you!! :)

Comment: Your logic seems wrong somewhere. You should leave the transaction observer in place always. I'd look into the "real" cause of your game crash. Perhaps give some more code here. Is a delegate getting deallocated?

Comment: the problem is if someone ads a payment (purchase) but then never completes it (or leaves the menu) the next time they go in and try purchase it it trys to add the same payment, see's that it is already there and crashes

Comment: You'll have to describe the flow of your process more. How can a user add a purchase but never complete it? Can you change your logic, algorithm, or UI so that is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Add this before you closing your Purchase ViewController

```
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().removeTransactionObserver(self)
```